# Unable to connect to secure websocket in DigitalOcean

Tags: express, nginx, websocket, digital-ocean

I'm having trouble setting up my WebSocket server in Digital Ocean.

I'm changing my actual domain name for domain.com for the question's sake.

I basically have a NodeJs WebSocket server that I'm trying to connect to a react app I'm hosting at Heroku. I'm getting the following error when attempting to connect:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://domain.com/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

Here's my server entry code:

```
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080
    const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem', 'utf-8')
    const certificate = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/cert.pem', 'utf-8')
    const credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate }


    const server = express()
    const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, server)
    httpsServer.listen(PORT)


    this.wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server: httpsServer })
```

I used cert-bot to secure my connection, as for Heroku is obligatory. So here's my nginx default config file, located at /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;


    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    # include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    # # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    # fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    # # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    # deny all;
    #}

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I also changed a bit my UFW config. Here's the output to sudo ufw status

```
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Just to be clear, I'm NOT using domain.com for real. I just changed it in the current question for privacy concerns, :D

Hope anyone can point me in the right direction. Not really sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the WebSocket error on status 200?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40070137/what-is-the-websocket-error-on-status-200)

Comment: A status of 200 means that the request did not reach the WebSocket handler. You will need a status of 101, switching protocols.

Comment: I understand the error, I'm just not sure what is blocking the websockets connection as the site works just fine.