# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200 - Next.js, Gun.js, ZEIT Now

Tags: next.js, gun, vercel

I’ve [deployed](https://maptivist.randymorantes.now.sh/) a Gun.js + Next.js app (source [here](https://github.com/rmorantes/maptivist)) via ZEIT Now, and I’m getting the following error from Chrome and Safari:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://maptivist.randymorantes.now.sh/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

From Firefox I'm getting:

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://maptivist.randymorantes.now.sh/.
```

Additionally, my Gun peers don't seem to be communicating with one another, probably because of this error. I gather this is probably [a problem with my server configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40110656/11845746), but I don't know how to apply the various solutions to my case ([example](https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/979#issuecomment-337934638)). The pertinent code seems to be:

```
// in next.config.js

const nextConfig = {
  target: 'serverless',
  webpack: customWebpackConfig,
  workboxOpts: {
    swDest: 'static/service-worker.js',
    runtimeCaching: [
      {
        urlPattern: /^https?.*/,
        handler: 'NetworkFirst',
        options: {
          cacheName: 'https-calls',
          networkTimeoutSeconds: 15,
          expiration: {
            maxEntries: 150,
            maxAgeSeconds: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 1 month
          },
          cacheableResponse: {
            statuses: [0, 200],
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The problem might also be how I'm using Gun (condensed):

```
import Gun from 'gun/gun'
import 'gun/sea'

const gun = Gun('https://maptivist.randymorantes.now.sh')
const user = gun.user()

user.create(valueAlias, valuePassword, response => {
  if (!response.err) {
    gun.get('users').set(user)
  }
})

// Only one user is found, the current user, despite there being
// two different users signed in on different devices.
gun.get('users').map(user => {
  console.log('user: ', user)
})
```

My understanding is that, upon creating users, my two peers should automatically sync these changes via the third peer sitting at my URL. However, while the [Gun + Next example](https://github.com/zrrrzzt/gun-next-example/blob/master/pages/index.js) uses one URL (`const gun = Gun('https://gunjs.herokuapp.com/gun')`), the [Gun todos example](https://gun.eco/docs/Todo-Dapp#step=Peers) uses two (`var gun = Gun(['http://localhost:8765/gun', 'https://gunjs.herokuapp.com/gun'])`). It's thus unclear to me whether, for my use case, I'm required to also pass a URL corresponding to my local machine.

URL combinations I've tried (after redeploying and refreshing) (it's also unclear whether appending "/gun" to URLs is required or convention):

```
const gun = Gun('https://maptivist.randymorantes.now.sh')
const gun = Gun('https://maptivist.randymorantes.now.sh/gun')
const gun = Gun(['http://localhost:3000/', 'https://maptivist.randymorantes.now.sh'])
const gun = Gun(['http://localhost:3000/', 'https://maptivist.randymorantes.now.sh/gun'])
const gun = Gun(['http://localhost:3000/gun', 'https://maptivist.randymorantes.now.sh/gun'])
```

I'm stumped. Please help! :-)

Answer (score 1):

@randy-morantes does ZEIT support websockets? If so, this should work.

I would guess that you'd need `/gun` though.

Is GUN even running on the ZEIT server? It does not look like it. Can you paste your server ZEIT code that uses GUN?

The browser does not need `localhost` to run GUN locally, it will run GUN directly in the browser. However, developers/users can also run GUN in NodeJS locally (separate from the browser), that is what `localhost` is referencing and will not work unless they have a locally running GUN NodeJS peer active (which is unlikely).

You can probably get more immediate help at the friendly https://gitter.im/amark/gun community chat, but PLEASE remember to come back here and update your post & answer with what you learn so others can benefit from it too. :)

Comment: I have no server code, which was the problem. `const gun = Gun('https://gunjs.herokuapp.com/gun')` got it working and also cleared up a misunderstanding of mine. I get now that Gun clients/peers must connect at some point to at least one server/super peer running Gun to persist data[(1)](https://gun.eco/docs/FAQ#what-is-the-difference-between-super-peer-and-other-peers)[(2)](https://github.com/amark/gun/blob/master/examples/express.js) and (I think) facilitate WebRTC connections [(3)](https://gun.eco/docs/Todo-Dapp#step=Peers) (the documentation on this could be clearer). Thanks for the help!